# Spacy: get position of word with entity tag

Tags: spacy

I'm trying to get the position of a word and it's entity tag by iterating over a sentence, as per the spacy docs

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(u'London is a big city in the United Kingdom.')
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.label_, ent.text)
    # GPE London
    # GPE United Kingdom
```

I've tried to get the position of the word with the tag ent.i and ent.idx however neither of these work and give the following error

```
AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.span.Span' object has no attribute 'i'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear to be ent.start

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(u'London is a big city in the United Kingdom.')
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.label_, ent.text, ent.start)
    #GPE London 0
    #GPE the United Kingdom 6
```